# Cannot understand some variables

Tags: perl

I have a code line:

```
$data->{nav}->{'current'}->{performance_gross}
```

I understand `$data` is scalar and `nav`, `performance_gross` are hash keys. But what is `'current'`?

Comment: An equivalent access would be `$data->{nav}{current}{performance_gross}`

Answer (score 1):

`nav`, `'current'` and `performance_gross` are expressions that respectively evaluate to the strings `nav`, `current` and `performance_gross`. These three strings are used as keys to different hashes.

The following are all equivalent:

```
$data->{'nav'}->{'current'}->{'performance_gross'}
$data->{'nav'}{'current'}{'performance_gross'}
$data->{nav}->{current}->{performance_gross}
$data->{nav}{current}{performance_gross}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl allows arbitrary expressions for the key in a hash lookup:

```
$hash{ arbitrary($code) . $here }
```

(The resulting string is used as the hash key.)

However, if the only thing between `{` and `}` is a simple identifier, it is quoted automatically:

```
$hash{ some_word }
# is equivalent to
$hash{ 'some_word' }
```

That's why you can often omit quotes in hash keys. But it's still valid to explicitly put a string literal there, and it means the same thing.